# Insert multiple images at once from a folder to Rows + Filename

Tags: image, vba, excel, import

Good morning everyone!

So I have taken this code from [extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1156-excel-insert-multiple-pictures.html](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1156-excel-insert-multiple-pictures.html) as it should be seen below.

What I want to know is if anyone can help me with -

Having all the photos import across 'Row B', instead of in a column fashion.
And how to add the 'File Names' (i.e. excel_image2.jpg) of said images, above each of their image in 'Row A'.

Thanks for all the help ahead of time!

```
Sub InsertPictures()
'Update 20140513
Dim PicList() As Variant
Dim PicFormat As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim sShape As Shape
On Error Resume Next
PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
If IsArray(PicList) Then
    xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
    For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
        Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
        Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
    xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what is "Row B"? Rows have numeric indexes and columns have letter ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Row B" is "Row 2" and "Row A" is "Row 1" you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertPictures()
    'Update 20140513
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim lLoop As Long

    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
            With Cells(2, 1).Offset(, lLoop - 1)
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, .Left, .top, .Width, .Height
                .Offset(-1).Value = Right(PicList(lLoop), Len(PicList(lLoop)) - InStrRev(PicList(lLoop), "\"))
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is just about what I'm looking for, except I don't need the whole "File location", right now it's doing i.e."C:\My Documents\etc etc"

I just need it to do the actual "image1.jpg" ?  

But you hit the nail on the head, sorry it's a slow start to the week, yes rows 1 and 2.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Thanks, just saw that you edited it!  You all are awesome i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only file name, try this:

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    'Update 20140513
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim PicFormat As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sShape As Shape
    Dim Filename As String
    On Error Resume Next
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
        For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
            Filename = Dir(PicList(lLoop), vbDirectory)  `~~> Getting only filename from path
            Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex) = Filename
            Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex + 1)
            Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
        xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**ManishChristian-** This does just the file name but it's in Column A and Column B.

**user3598756-** has it going to 'Row 1' for the 'File Address' and 'Row 2'for the images which is exactly what I wanted.

I just need either *Manish's* to go from Column A and B to Rows 1 and 2 or for *user3598756* to chop down to just the file name with extension, not the full path.

I tried just adding "Filename = Dir(PicList(lLoop), vbDirectory)  `~~> Getting only filename from path" (without your comment) to Manish's lLoop but it error'd.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer! Delete it and edit your question